# IBM Notes: Eclipse Plugin deployment to framework directory

Tags: deployment, eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes

I am not totally sure, if this question is in the right forum here, but as it is about a development environment and deploying developments I think it is save to ask.

I have a plugin for the IBM Notes client that I need to install silently in the background.

I used "CustomizeAddon.exe" to create a package and created an install.addon.xml with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ibm-portal-composite>
    <domain-object name="com.ibm.rcp.installmanifest">
        <object-data>
            <install>
                <installfeature id="Jabber4Notes" required="true">
                    <requirements>
                        <feature id="com.endava.jabber4notes.feature"
                            version="2.11.8.298" match="compatible"
                            shared="true" mergeaction="add"
                            url="jar:${installer.root}/updateSite.zip!/" />
                        <feature id="com.endava.jabber4notes.IMPFragmentFeature"
                            version="2.11.8.298" match="compatible"
                            shared="true" mergeaction="add"
                            url="jar:${installer.root}/updateSite.zip!/" />
                    </requirements>
                </installfeature>
            </install>
        </object-data>
    </domain-object>
</ibm-portal-composite>
```

But although I use the parameter shared="true" the plugin always installs to the workspace directory instead of the feature- directory.

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to have write permissions on the shared site.

If that's not the problem try to use colocation affinity to specify that the deployment site should be the same of another plugin; `com.ibm.rcp.site.anchor.shared.feature` is always installed on the shared site so you could add this:

```
colocation-affinity="com.ibm.rcp.site.anchor.shared.feature"
```

Here you can find more information regarding this topic: [LINK](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lewiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Lotus%20Expeditor%206.2.3%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Controlling_the_feature_install_location_XPD623&content=pdcontent)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately the collocation-affinity is ignored as well... And I definitively have write access to program directory

Comment: I had to resign the jar after changing the colocation-affinity within the feature.xml file, then it worked. THANX